# Does a 'unique' column field imply an index with MySQL, and if so, why?

Tags: mysql, optimization, database

Although I understand that it is very convinient to have an index on a unique column - to easily and efficiently check for value collision, I think it should be up to the programmer to specify whether a unique field column is to have an index or not, with regards to size- vs speed- optimization.

As far as I understand MySQL automatically indexes a table column that is specified as unique. Is it so?

Is there any reason MySQL seemingly cannot have unique columns WITHOUT indexes? Yes, every value insertion/update will be O(number_of_rows) operation without one, but like I said, shouldn't the programmer be taxed with the decision?

Just curious!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> As far as I understand MySQL automatically indexes a table column that is specified as unique. Is it so?

Yes. It's not necessarily 'automatic' though, it's implicit. `UNIQUE` is *type* of index, so of course that column is indexed.

> Is there any reason MySQL seemingly cannot have unique columns WITHOUT indexes?

Because it would be silly for MySQL to do a full table scan on each `INSERT`/`UPDATE` to uphold the unique constraint.

**Edit**:

> Yes, every value insertion/update will be O(number_of_rows) operation without one, but like I said, shouldn't the programmer be taxed with the decision?

Why would a programmer want to manually enforce basic data integrity outside of the data storage layer? I understand where you're going with this, but the fact is an index can't possibly *hurt* anything (it just takes a bit more space) - so there really isn't a decision to consider.

Comment: In fact, one reason to use a DBMS is to maintain data integrity.

Comment: Data integrity and data indexing, even though related, are two orthogonal concepts, no?

Comment: @amn, yes, I believe they are.  And most of the time the solution to data integrity isn't so elegant as this particular case.  Many times it comes down to having to physically check that the data that is supposed to be there is actually there.  Of course this also depends on the RDMS, support for foreign keys, key constraints, etc.